# Emacs: current buffer's coding system

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

I have used to pc for developing erlang program, one is mac os x 10.6, the other is mac os x 10.7.

In `".emacs"` file of both pc, it contain the following script

```
;;handle emacs utf-8 input
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

But when I input remark including Chinese characters in one pc and saved, and download to the other pc. The chinese characters can't be shown correctly. The same story for reverse operation.

I want to know how to check the current file's encoding type? Is there any command can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `buffer-file-coding-system`. `M-x describe-variable` will tell you more about it, and you can set it by `M-x eval-expression` and use `(setq buffer-file-coding-system 'coding-system-i-want)`. That will set it for a single buffer; once you've got it working, you can add entries to `file-coding-system-alist` to permanently set the option as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

you may also set

coding-system-for-write
coding-system-for-read

Answer (score 1):

To modify the coding system in order to to read and write all ‘.txt’ files using the coding system chinese-iso-8bit, you can execute this Lisp expression:

```
(modify-coding-system-alist 'file "\\.txt\\'" 'chinese-iso-8bit)
```

For more informations see [Recognizing Coding Systems](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html).